# Can't get HTML form data to submit to a Flask function

Tags: python, html, database, flask

I have an HTML form in `index.html` whose data I want to send to the `submit()` function in my `application.py` file upon submitting.

I can't get the function to run, though, when clicking submit

How can I correctly submit the data to run the submit() function while also keeping the URL at the browser

Here's the HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('submit') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <label>Coordinates:</label>
    <input type="text" name="coords"> <!-- COORDS -->
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Year:</label>
    <input type="text" name="year"> <!-- YEAR -->
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Range</label>
    <select name="range"> <!-- RANGE -->
        <option value="one">1700s or earlier</option>
        <option value="two">early 1800s</option>
        <option value="three">mid 1800s</option>
        <option value="four">late 1800s</option>
        <option value="five">1900s</option>
        <option value="six">1910s</option>
        <option value="seven">1920s</option>
        <option value="eight">1930s</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"> <!-- PHOTO -->
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Caption:</label>
    <input type="text" name="caption"> <!-- CAPTION -->
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Source:</label>
    <input type="text" name="source"> <!-- SOURCE -->
    <br/><br/>

    <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the Python code. The content of the submit() function doesn't matter, I just want to just activate at the moment.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import mysql.connector
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename #input validation for files
from datetime import datetime
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    print('test');

    # get the form data from the request
    coords = request.form['coords']
    year = request.form['year']
    range = request.form['range']
    photo = request.files['photo']
    caption = request.form['caption']
    source = request.form['source']

    print(coords)

    # save the photo to the file manager
    # timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    # filename = secure_filename(f"{timestamp}_{photo.filename}")
    filename = secure_filename(photo.filename)
    photo.save(os.path.join('photos/', filename))

    # connect to the database
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='REDACTED', password='REDACTED', host='localhost', database='genealu6_markers', port=3306)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    # insert the form data into the database
    query = ("INSERT INTO contacts (coordinates, year, yearrange, photo, caption, source) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
    data = (coords, year, range, filename, caption, source)
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    cnx.commit()

    # close the database connection
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

    return 'Data submitted successfully'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The Python function doesn't run, and I also get linked to a URL ending in `/%7B%7B%20url_for('submit')%20%7D%7D`, which I do not want to happen.

I tried running the code and hitting submit, to no avail.

I tried sending messages to the terminal at the beginning of the submit() function to see if it is actually running, which it does not.

Also, I actually have this code uploaded on a website, to see for yourself when hitting submit (don't bother actually filling out the form): http://openmediamap.com/

Comment: Probably a web server misconfiguration. You're not actually loading a rendered template, it's just loading the HTML file directly so your variable for the form action is not changing to an actual URL